# How to Use the BingMapsTask in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone, bing-maps

This is working just fine, when i click on button it going to the direction in search term. But in small town in Europe it's simple wont work out. How can i search with coordinates?

```
 using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;
    using System.Device.Location;



    BingMapsTask Map = new BingMapsTask();
    Map.SearchTerm = "Koramangala , Bangalore";
    Map.ZoomLevel = 2;
    Map.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```
var task = new BingMapsTask();
task.Center = new GeoCoordinate(41.145495, −73.994901);
task.ZoomLevel = 10;
task.Show();
```